# ERROR [42000] [IBM] [System I Access ODBC Driver] [DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 Token _ was not valid

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am receiving the error

```
ERROR [42000][IBM][System I Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 Token _ was not valid. Valid tokens: ( + - ? : DAY INF LAG NAN RID ROW RRN CASE CAST CHAR DATE DAYS.
```

when running the following SQL command:

```
select 
DDMAST."ACCTNO"
from DAT589.DDMAST
where DATOP7 = (TO_CHAR(_ADD_DAYS(CURDATE(),-1), 'yyyyDDD'))
```

I have tried removing the _ from different parts of this command but will receive other error messages that the command is not valid.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is **IBM Db2** Syntax for `ADD_DAYS` function. See this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSCRJT_5.0.4/com.ibm.swg.im.bigsql.commsql.doc/doc/r0061468.html) for details.

```
select DDMAST."ACCTNO" from DAT589.DDMAST where DATOP7 = (TO_CHAR(ADD_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE, -1), 'yyyyDDD'))
```

Might want to try this instead.

```
select DDMAST."ACCTNO" from DAT589.DDMAST where DATOP7 = (TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE - 1 DAY, 'yyyyDDD'))
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I use the syntax provided, I get the error:  ERROR [42S02] [IBM][System I Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0204 - ADD_DAYS in *LIBL type *N not found.  Any feedback?  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Matt, try 2nd query

Comment: First syntax is not valid for DB2 for i. The correct docs for DB2 for i are [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzintro.htm). You provided docs for DB2 Big SQL which appears to be a fourth flavor of DB2.